# null reference exception on using DefaultIfEmpty()

Tags: c#, linq, nullreferenceexception

I wrote the below sql query

```
SELECT       *

FROM          dbo.PR_ADDRESS LEFT OUTER JOIN
              dbo.Book_MarkText ON dbo.PR_ADDRESS.GroupID = dbo.Book_MarkText.BMData
where 
        dbo.PR_ADDRESS.GroupID = dbo.Book_MarkText.BMData 

OR  
        PR_ADDRESS.GroupID in ('001','002','003')
```

to LINQ as

```
string[] srGroupIDs =  new string[] { "001", "002", "003" };
 var objResult =
      (from PR_ADDRESS in dtPR_ADDRESS.AsEnumerable()
       join
          Book_MarkText in dtBookmarkText.AsEnumerable() on
         (string)PR_ADDRESS["GroupID"] equals (string)Book_MarkText["BMData"] 
                                                               into Book_MarkText_join

          from Book_MarkText_Temp in Book_MarkText_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
          where srGroupIDs.Contains(PR_ADDRESS["Groupid"])
             || ((string)PR_ADDRESS["Groupid"] == (string)Book_MarkText_Temp["BMData"])

            select new
            {
                ID = PR_ADDRESS["ID"],
                Name1 = PR_ADDRESS["Name1"]
            }).ToList();
```

But Gives me null reference exception on line

```
 where  srGroupIDs.Contains(PR_ADDRESS["Groupid"]) 
              ||  ((string)PR_ADDRESS ["Groupid"] == (string)Book_MarkText_Temp["BMData"])
```

Why ?

If i remove `.DefaultIfEmpty()` , this works without exception , but i need 'LEFT OUTER JOIN'  so can't remove `.DefaultIfEmpty()` .   How can i solve it ?

**Edit**  :-

I added the OR case also , Hope now it is clear

Comment: Well you need to handle the case where `Book_MarkText_Temp` is null, because that's what `DefaultIfEmpty()` does - where it would be empty, you end up with a sequence with a single default value... null in this case. It's not clear why you've got the `where` clause at all though, given that you've just *done* the join...

Comment: I cannot remove the where clause because there is an OR condition also  in the where clause , which is essential , not mentioned in the question .

Comment: Right, so you've decided to leave important information out of the question... that makes it very hard to help you. The where clause you've provided is pointless, in both the SQL and the LINQ. You're doing a join, and then checking the join worked, basically... but turning it into an inner join at the same time.

Comment: Solved ... ! Thank you

Comment: Well it's a *bit* clearer now, but it's still horribly formatted. Please put some effort into presenting questions as readably as possible. Ideally, we shouldn't have to scroll horizontally at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by handling `Book_MarkText_Temp` null as Jon Skeet's comment .Thanks for finding time to help me .

```
 string[] srGroupIDs =  new string[] { "001", "002", "003" };

var objResult =
        (from PR_ADDRESS in dtPR_ADDRESS.AsEnumerable() 
                join
             Book_MarkText in dtBookmarkText.AsEnumerable() on
            (string)PR_ADDRESS ["GroupID"] equals (string)Book_MarkText["BMData"] into Book_MarkText_join

    from Book_MarkText_Temp in Book_MarkText_join.DefaultIfEmpty()                      
    where Book_MarkText_Temp == null ? srGroupIDs.Contains(PR_ADDRESS["Groupid"]) :

    srGroupIDs.Contains(PR_ADDRESS["Groupid"])
    || ((string)PR_ADDRESS["Groupid"] == (string)Book_MarkText_Temp["BMData"])

    select new {
                  ID = PR_ADDRESS ["ID"],
                  Name1 = PR_ADDRESS ["Name1"]
                }).ToList();
```